# How to integrate tinymce for local image uploading at codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, tinymce

```
<script>

    tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea',
        plugins: 'image code',
        toolbar: 'undo redo | image code',

        // without images_upload_url set, Upload tab won't show up
        images_upload_url: '<?= base_url("upload.php"); ?>',

        // override default upload handler to simulate successful upload
        images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
            var xhr, formData;

            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.withCredentials = false;
            xhr.open('POST', '<?= base_url("upload.php"); ?>');

            xhr.onload = function() {
                var json;

                if (xhr.status != 200) {
                    failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
                    return;
                }

                json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

                if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
                    failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
                    return;
                }

                success(json.location);
            };

            formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());

            xhr.send(formData);
        },
    });

</script>
```

// this code does not work

Answer (score 0):

Every file-manager need to any text editor like [ckeditor](https://ckeditor.com/) you must use an editor this file-manager has a documentation and installation you must read it in the main site.
you can see documentation in this URL https://www.tinymce.com/docs/